# Web Service Java no OpenShift usando Tomcat 6 (JBoss EWS 1.0)

Tags: java, android, mysql, cloud, openshift

Estou tentando criar um Web Service em JAVA para poder ser consumido por uma aplicação Android.
Preciso usar uma tecnologia Cloud, e só encontrei o OpenShift gratuito e melhor recomendado por enquanto...
Bem, já criei meu projeto no Eclipse. Já tenho todas as ferramentas. Já enviei o projeto para o OpenShift, etc.
O problema é o seguinte:
(Obs.: sou iniciante)

Criei uma classe de conexão com o banco de dados:

```
package conectaMySql;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ConectaMySql {

    private static final String URL = "link do MySql dado pela OpenShift";
    private static final String USER = "login do MySql dado pela OpenShift";
    private static final String SENHA = "senha do MySql dada pela OpenShift";

    public static Connection obterConexao() throws SQLException{

        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");     
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, SENHA);
    }
}
```

Criei uma outra classe com os seguintes dados:

```
package classesDao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import classes.*;
import conectaMySql.*;

public class AdministradorDao {

    public boolean insertAdmin(Administrador admin){

        try {
            Connection conn = ConectaMySql.obterConexao();

            String queryInserir = "INSERT INTO Administrador VALUES (?, ?)";

            PreparedStatement ppStm = conn.prepareStatement(queryInserir);

            ppStm.setString(1, admin.getLogin());
            ppStm.setString(2, admin.getSenha());

            ppStm.executeUpdate();

            conn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

Desconsiderando o conceito de MVC, rsrsrs... Como posso fazer para disponibilizar essa classe como serviço?
Pesquisei muito na internet, mas não manjo muito bem de inglês (sei que estou lascado, e a ferramenta de tradução me ajudou pra caramba), mas infelizmente não encontrei nada concreto.
Vi algumas coisas sobre web.xml, etc... Mas ainda estou na escuridão! E agora, quem poderá me ajudar?

Comment: Só quero meu _wsdl_ :(

Comment: Você quer expor o seu DAO como um serviço SOAP, é isso?

Comment: exatamente isso! Vi que preciso configurar algum xml, mas não tive sucesso, rsrs..

Comment: Precisa ser SOAP?

Comment: Jedaias, porque não faz um WebService REST usando a API JAX-RS? É bem simples, só vai depender de qual implementação que o servidor tem, ou você pode embarcar no seu projeto, seja o RestEasy ou por exemplo o Jersey.

Answer (score 1):

Independente de ser OpenShift ou qualquer outro ambiente, você precisa disponibilizar sua implementação usando alguma implementação do protocolo SOAP.

A biblioteca [Apache Axis2](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/) é a mais usada no mercado. Inclusive com o Eclipse WTP (plugin Web Tools Platform), você consegue criar e editar um WSDL e então gerar as classes *stub* para implementar seu web service. Depois você precisa publicar isso como uma aplicação web. Não tem como eu fazer um tutorial aqui, mas tem vários tutoriais que você pode encontar por aí.

Outra opção é usar o [Spring Boot](https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/), que acredito irá facilitar mais a sua vida. O Spring Boot é um projeto relativamente novo do Spring Framework que trabalha fortemente com o conceito de Convenção sobre Configuração (CoC - Convention over Configuration), sendo que ele geralmente encurta e simplifica bastante o *setup* do projeto.

Porém, independente da opção, é importante que você estude e entenda o que está fazendo, pois mesmo para algo simples você vai precisar saber um pouco sobre a arquitetura de um projeto web e onde implementar cada método.

Uma dica importante é que num projeto, e especialmente um que envolva *cloud*, você nunca deve abrir uma conexão manualmente como está fazendo nesse projeto. Use um framework como o Spring para gerenciar seus *data sources* ou uma biblioteca de *connection pool*, por exemplo.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda meu amigo. Mas eu estava tentando usar o Apache Axis2 no OpenShift e não consegui, vou dar mais uma olhada aqui.

Comment: Cara, eu consegui criar um WebService local usando o Apache Axis2 e disponibilizar um WSDL, o problema é colocar isso no OpenShift.